# psexec : argument line with doublequotes

Tags: ant, psexec

I need to start a `.bat` file on a remote pc via `psexec` . The remote pc has *usr* and *pwd* set:

```
usr= username 
pwd= password"123
```

In `cmd` it works fine , just put a `\` in front of `"`
(`psexec \\remote-pc -d -u username -p password\"123`)

But, the point is that I have this arg line defined in my *build.xml* and i'm not able to start it by using `ANT`.
I tried by changing the `"` with `&quot;` and other stuffs i found but no way.

any idea? maybe it's easier to change the *pwd* of my machines :-)

thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a rule of thumb use 1-n nested arg value elements instead of arg line,
see [ant manual commandline arguments](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#arg).
Splitting your arg line into several arg value ... should work, see :

```
<exec executable="c:\pstools\psexec.exe">
 <arg value="\\hostname"/>
 <arg value="/accepteula"/>
 <arg value="cmd"/>
 <arg value="/c"/>
 <arg value="echo"/>
 <arg value="password&quot;123"/>
</exec>
```

output :

```
[exec] PsExec v1.98 - Execute processes remotely
[exec] Copyright (C) 2001-2010 Mark Russinovich
[exec] Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com
[exec] cmd exited with error code 0.
```

whereas :

```
<exec executable="c:\pstools\psexec.exe">
 <arg line="\\hostname /accepteula cmd /c echo password&quot;123"/>
</exec>
```

output :

```
BUILD FAILED
.. unbalanced quotes in \\hostname /accepteula cmd /c echo password"123
```